# If we put diamagnetic material under strong electromagnet, would the opposing magnetic fields be strong enough to attract ferromagnetic materials?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, material-science

Suppose we put a diamagnetic material (such as Bismuth or Pyrolytic Carbon) under a strong magnet (see image below). It would create opposing magnetic fields. Would the opposing magnetic field be strong enough to attract ferromagnetic or paramagnetic materials? Or could it induce magnetic fields in paramagnetic or ferromagnetic materials with high magnetic permeability? And how we can calculate the strength of the magnetic field?[image]

Comment: Just an observation (I'll let someone else do the maths): The strongest diamagnetic materials have a susceptibility of $\sim 10^{-4}$ and so the magnetisation of the ferro/paramagnetic material will most likely be caused by the top magnet more so than the diamagnet...

Comment: I agree but what will happen when strong diamagnetic material as a ferromagnetic would be in cell made of weak diamagnetic?

Comment: I don't understand why would the poles of the diamagnetic material be in this layout.

Comment: Maybe consider a superconductor

Answer (score 0):

The opposite force resulted from diamagnetic material will be weak to attract paramagnetic materials even if you add more magnets to the diamagnetic material.